# Cant install a nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

From nuget package manager I am trying to install a package. When I try this it fails on dependency Unable to resolve dependency 'Syste'.

Is this short for system.?

```
Unable to resolve dependency 'Syste'.
```

shows up nothing in my google search[image]

**UPDATE**
[image]

Comment: Could you check your `packages.config` if contains such dependency?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply no packages.config does not contain this dependency

Comment: Could you specify which package you are trying to install, it seems that it has typo in dependency list, so try to check complete dependency graph.

Comment: I have attached an image of the dependencies from nugetpackage install when I have my package selected (OP)